# as3 fullscreen video performance with stage.fullScreenSourceRect

Tags: actionscript-3, video

Why does defining a Rectangle object on the stage improve video playback performance?

Without the following a 1080P video plays back at 17fps

With the following it is both larger(fills width of screen) AND plays quicker.
Why??

```
var screenRectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920,1080);
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = screenRectangle;
```

Comment: meta data in encoding is probably missing

Comment: what fullScreenSourceRect does is tell flash to only render the area defined by the rectangle and in order to do that flash enables hardware acceleration and obviously scaling

Comment: here is more detailed http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#fullScreenSourceRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found the answer It enables hardware scaling

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001538.html